# How to make ".well-known/pki-validation/fileauth.txt" publicly accessible in cakePHP 2x?

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl, cakephp-2.0

I have the CakePHP 2x framework installed on my [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) apache server. I issued an SSL certificate successfully and suggested to place the auth file on ".well-known/pki-validation/" location, that is done already.
they suggest like ".well-known/pki-validation/fileauth.txt" should be publicly accessible.

when i am trying to access "www.abc.com/.well-known/pki-validation/fileauth.txt"
i am getting following error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function link() on null in
> /home/abccom/public_html/app/views/layouts/default.ctp on line 18

How do we make it done?

Thanks

Comment: in your public directory or wherever index.php is located, create folder structure like `.well-known/pki-validation/fileauth.txt` - this is domain control validation for the ssl file that you just added. this is to prove your domain name ownership. you should be able to get `fileauth.txt` from wherever you got your ssl cert from.

Comment: @kenzotenma the folder structure has already created like "/public_html/.well-known/pki-validation/fileauth.txt". but it is not accessible

Comment: server? is it rightly pointing at `public_html` ?

Comment: apache server. and yes it is rightly pointed in public_html as I mentioned in the previous comment. This site is build in cakePHP 2x

Comment: what response do you get when hitting on this url

Comment: @kenzotenma Fatal error: Call to a member function link() on null in /home/fmfcom/public_html/app/views/layouts/default.ctp on line 18

Comment: What does your `.htaccess` file look like? I'm guessing that it doesn't include the conditions to exclude existing files from being redirected to index.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP 2 default public folder is:
`/app/webroot`
you may check if your server publish folder is proper set to the above, if not, you will face this kind of issue with static files, your server may have to point to something like `/public_html/app/webroot` if server is Ubuntu based check if Apache mod_rewrite is enabled, to enable type `sudo a2enmod rewrite` in console, after all changes restart Apache.

Comment: yes, by default its public folder is /app/webroot/. but I can't take risk of changing it. any suggestion?

Comment: There is no risk changing that, it is expected and will present malfunction if not properly defined as you can see. By default the .htaccess inside / will redirect requests to /app/webroot/ and thats why you cannot use / as your publication path.

Comment: ok, but if I make "publc_html/" as public path then another path that is already accessing via through "app/webroot/" could be affected. 
should I make a route or something else?